# Иногда мяч проходит через объект

Tags: unity3d

Добрые люди, пожалуйста, помогите страдальцам

- ballForce = 210.
- Gravity Y = -18.

Код:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public Material[] balls;

    public static GameManager instance;
    public GameObject ball;
    public Transform target;
    public float ballForce;
    Plane plane = new Plane (Vector3.forward,0);
    public bool readyToshoot;
    void Awake()
    {
        if(instance == null) 
        {
            instance = this;
        } else 
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {

        ball.SetActive(true);
        readyToshoot = true;
    }
    private bool IsPointerOverUIObject() {
        PointerEventData eventDataCurrentPosition = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
        eventDataCurrentPosition.position = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
        List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();
        EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(eventDataCurrentPosition, results);
        return results.Count > 0;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("index")==0)
        {
            ball.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = balls[0];
        }
        if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("index")==1)
        {
            ball.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = balls[1];
        }
        if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("index")==2)
        {
            ball.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = balls[2];
        }
        if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("index")==3)
        {
            ball.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = balls[3];
        }
        if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("index")==4)
        {
            ball.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = balls[4];
        }
        if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("index")==5)
        {
            ball.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = balls[5];
        }

        Vector3 dir = target.position - ball.transform.position;



        if (!IsPointerOverUIObject() && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && readyToshoot) 
        {

            ball.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;
            ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(dir * ballForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
            readyToshoot = false;
        }

        float dist;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (plane.Raycast (ray, out dist)) 
        {

            Vector3 point = ray.GetPoint(dist);
            target.position = new Vector3(point.x, point.y, 0);
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Чем помочь забыли написать.

Comment: Иногда мяч проходит через объект

Comment: `FixedUpdate` в этом не совсем хорошо будет, он не всегда срабатывает. И вы не сохраняете начальную позицию меча и конечную, из-за этого при большой скорости или не очень, мяч может пролететь сквозь препятствия. В методе `Start` добавьте начальную позицию меча и в методе `Update` текущую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continious Dynamic возможно поможет, но:

1. Вы уверены, что IsPointerOverUIObject() должна вызываться в FixedUpdate()? Это же не каждый кадр происходит..
2. Зачем вызываете каждый раз GetComponent() ? Это же дорого. Почему не закешировать материал в классе Ball, если он у вас вообще есть..
3. Направление находите так `Vector3 dir = target.position - ball.transform.position;`, а потом расчитываете силу так `dir * ballForce`. В этом случае будет учтено не только направление, но и магнитуда вектора. Оно так и должно быть у вас? Если нет , то надо брать нормальзованный вектор `dir.normalized`
4. Не уверен вообще в эффективности метода IsPointerOverUIObject(). Не вникал. Но зачем вы каждый раз создаете новый список? `List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();` , если можно один раз создать и потом чистить. Это дешевле. Хотя, здесь скорее всего можно проще сделать. Вы просто скопировали с форума код и все.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, ваш мяч движется порой слишком быстро, и проскакивает препятствие между двумя расчетами физики. В настройках коллизий надо поменять на Continuous Dynamic.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html